# Why need use express static

Tags: node.js, express

Sorry for silly question but i really want to know why we need to use it . I know stactic file are files that aren't being generated as they're loaded, but must be sent to the browser when requested .

I would appreciate if anyone can explain for me these questions.

Comment: You kind of answered your own question there. You need `express.static` so your server can serve files that aren't being generated on the fly. It handles all the file loading and prevents [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) attacks.

Comment: @JoeClay Thank you, your answer really made it more clear to me

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a scenario where you are creating an API as well as want to serve your static assets (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc) from the same Express application.

In this case it makes a lot of sense to define a folder - normally it's called 'public' - and have all the previously mentioned static assets there, e.g.:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now that's out of the way you can go and create your API using Node.JS/Express with a nice separation of what's a static asset and what's loaded dynamically by your app. At least this is how I use it. I hope this will help.

Comment: I would also add that in production it's often more efficient to not involve Express in serving static content and use Nginx to serve that instead

Comment: I concur @MatthewDaly